# Python. Can Someone Explain me the Following Output?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, logic

```
a = [0,1,2,3]
for a[-1] in a:
    print a[-1]
```

The Output of the Code is 
0
1
2
2

How ?

Comment: Was this so Straight foward that someone actually down voted this question ?

Comment: @RudreshAjgonkar This question doesn't have any relation to a real-world problem. There is a special site here on stack exchange ( https://codegolf.stackexchange.com )for "gaming" with such curiosities - and there are plenty of them, some even more surprising than this one. Sometimes this kind of questions will be so massive downvoted that they become closed or deleted, sometimes not ... and no, I haven't downvoted this question, but can understand how it comes.

Comment: Thanks @Claudio for your response. I ll take care next Time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of your for-loop as equivalent to the following:

```
iterator = iter(a)
while True:
    try:
        a[-1] = next(iterator)
        print a[-1]
    except StopIteration as e:
        break
```

So you see, when `a[-1] = next(iterator)` the current value returned by `next` is assigned to `a[-1]`, which is the last element of the list.

So,

iteration 1: `a = [*0*, 1, 2, 0]`, and `print a[-1]` prints `0`

iteration 2: `a = [0, *1*, 2, 1]`, and `print a[-1]` prints `1`

iteration 3: `a = [0, 1, *2*, 2]`, and `print a[-1]` prints `2`

iteration 4: `a = [0, 1, 2, *2*]`, and `print a[-1]` prints `2`

I've put *'s around what `next` returns.

Comment: Thanks for the Detailed Explanation.

Answer (score 1):

On each loop iteration, the next list element is assigned to the loop target.  The loop target here is `a[-1]`.  So the loop effectively does:

```
a[-1] = a[0] # 0
print(a[-1])

a[-1] = a[1] # 1
print(a[-1])

a[-1] = a[2] # 2
print(a[-1])
```

Note that the last one here sets `a[-1]` to 2.  This means a is now `[0, 1, 2, 2]`.  The last loop iteration now reads this last value (`a[3]`) and prints it, giving the output you see.

This kind of oddness can arise when the loop target is not independent of what it's iterating over.

Answer (score 1):

You can

> copy/paste your small piece of code [HERE ( pythontutor.com )](http://pythontutor.com/visualize.html#mode=display)

to **see yourself step by step what happens**.

Sometimes is visualisation worth more than thousand words ... and YES, as explained in all the other answers, TWO things happens while this loop is running at the same time:

a value from a list is provided AND the list itself is updated with a new value. That is what produces the surprising output.

Answer (score 1):

First off, a[-1] is the last element of the list a.
So, every time the iterator takes an element from the list and assigns it to the last element of a.

```
a[-1]=0 #when first loop runs
a[-1]=1 #when loop runs second time
a[-1]=2 #when loop runs third time
```

So, now your list is [0,1,2,2] because when the loop ran 3rd time, it assigned the last element of the list, the value of 2.

Now, when the loop runs the 4th and last time it takes the last element, assigns it to a[-1] which itself is the last element and prints it. So, effectively, it prints 2 which was the last element of our list a after 3 iterations.

This is happening because you are iterating over and modifying the same object during the iteration.